# toString method in my program is not right

Tags: java, arrays, tostring, sentence

The task is to Create a class called Sentence which will be used to represent a sentence of English text. It should have the following features:

A private instance variable, words, of type String array, that holds the words that make up the sentence.

A constructor that has a single String array as argument. The elements of the array will be the words in the sentence.

A toString() method that overrides the inherited toString() provided in the Object class. This should return a single string composed of all the words in the sentence, separated by single spaces, in the order they are held in words.

A method, shortest(), that returns a String containing the shortest word in the sentence. (If there is more than one shortest word, returns one of them).

A method, longest(), that returns a String containing the longest word in the sentence. (If there is more than one longest word, returns one of them). 
A method, meanLength(), that returns the average length of the words in the sentence.

A method, sorted(), that returns the words in the sentence sorted into alphabetical order in a String array. This method should not modify the array words. 
My code is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sentence {
    private String[] words;

public Sentence(String[] words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

   public String toString() {
        String sentence = "";
        for (String word : words) sentence += word + " ";

        return sentence;
    }

    public String shortest() {
        String shortString = words[0];

        for (String string: words) {
            if (string.length() < shortString.length()) {
                shortString = string;
            }
        }

        return shortString;
    }

    public String longest() {
        String longString = words[0];

        for (String string: words) {
            if (string.length() > longString.length()) {
                longString = string;
            }
        }

        return longString;
    }

    public double meanLength(){
        String[] strArray = Arrays.toString(words).split(" ");
        int numWords = words.length;
        int totalCharacters = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
             totalCharacters = totalCharacters + words[i].length();

        return totalCharacters/numWords;
    }

    public String[] sorted(){
        Arrays.sort(words);
        return words;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] wordList = {"A", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
          Sentence text = new Sentence(wordList);
          System.out.println(text);
          System.out.println("Shortest word: " + text.shortest());
          System.out.println("Longest word: " + text.longest());
          System.out.printf("Mean word length:%5.2f\n",text.meanLength());
          String[] sortedText = text.sorted();
          System.out.print("Sorted: " + Arrays.toString(sortedText)); 
        }
}
```

I don't think my toString method is correct and neither is my mean word length. Can someone explain to me the correct way of implementing those two methods please? Thank you :).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `toString` method. However, if you intend to return a double in `meanLength` you should cast int to double prior to any division. i.e. `totalCharacters/numWords` should be (double)totalCharacters/(double)numWords`

Comment: @CalvinP. thanks for that, umm I thought there was something wrong with the toString method because I have to create a copy of the array so when the sorting happens, the oirignal array doesn't get affected.

Comment: Only a tip about performance. In your toString method I recommend to use a StringBuilder to construct the sentence. The `+` operator causes a lot of string copying.

Comment: I'm actually not seeing anywhere that you attempt to use your `Sentence.toString`. You always seem to call `Arrays.toString` instead